# Converter texto dentro de uma <div> em links com codigo!

Tags: php, html, css, regex

Tenho uma div com o seguinte aspecto

```
<div class="tvshowlinks">
1
https://link1.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link2.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link3.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link4.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt

2
https://link1.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link2.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link3.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
https://link4.com/qweeqweqw,https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt
</div>
```

queria transformar em algo do tipo abaixo... é possivel com php?

```
<?php
// codigo aqui 
?>

<div class="tvshowlinks">
<span>1ª temporada</span>
<a href="https://link1.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 1</a>
<a href="https://link2.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 2</a>
<a href="https://link3.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 3</a>
<--!poderá ter mais de 24 episódios -->
<a href="https://link2.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 24</a>

<span>2ª temporada</span>
<a href="https://link1.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 1</a>
<a href="https://link2.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 2</a>
<a href="https://link3.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 3</a>
<--!poderá ter mais de 24 episódios -->
<a href="https://link3.com/qweeqweqw?legendas=https://segundolink.com/qweeqweqw.srt">Episódio 24</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o for no php para gerar esse links e numerar esse episódios.
Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que os links serão relativamente "seguidos", você pode utilizar um loop para gerar os finais de cada episódio em sequência. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```js
var i;

for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {

  //Declarando variáveis
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linha = document.createElement("BR");
  var link = document.createTextNode("Episodio " + i);

  //Aplicando funções e descrições do link
  a.appendChild(link);
  a.title = "Episodio " + i;
  a.href = "http://www.examplo.com/episodio/" + i;
  a.insertBefore(linha, a.nextSibling); //Aqui você vai adicionar a quebra de linha após cada resultado do loop
  document.body.appendChild(a); //Aqui você vai gerar os links com todas as configurações acima

}
```

```html
<div id="links">
</div>
```